# How to sort a nested dictionary by a nested key

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array

i couldn't really find the question i was looking for, and didn't understand the ones that are already there.
i have a 2 d dictionary like so:

```
 {'alim2': {'running': 1470.0, 'swimming': 650.0, 'total': 2120.0, 'cycling': 0}, 'brownv4': {'running': 0, 'swimming': 0, 'total': 0, 'cycling': 0},
'mahroosm5': {'running': 1180.0, 'swimming': 590, 'total': 6647.0, 'cycling': 4877.0},
'turnerb3': {'running': 1180.0, 'swimming': 500, 'total': 1680.0, 'cycling': 0}}
```

the numbers are basically the calories burnt by each sport, and i need to make the program to sort the keys (the username like 'brownv4') in ascending order of the 'total' value.
it would also be very convenient if the output could jsut be the key of he dictionary, in this case the username.
sot he output would be like:
mahroosm5, alim2, turnerb3, brownv4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really sorting since dictionary's are unordered but you can try using `sorted()` and `key` a nice article [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-python), If you really need a dict you can put the `sorted()` return value inside an [Ordered Dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes)

```
import pprint

my_dict = {'alim2': {'running': 1470.0, 'swimming': 650.0, 'total': 2120.0, 'cycling': 0}, 'brownv4': {'running': 0, 'swimming': 0, 'total': 0, 'cycling': 0},
'mahroosm5': {'running': 1180.0, 'swimming': 590, 'total': 6647.0, 'cycling': 4877.0},
'turnerb3': {'running': 1180.0, 'swimming': 500, 'total': 1680.0, 'cycling': 0}}

pprint.pprint(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda key_:key_[1]['total']))
```

**Output:**

```
[('brownv4', {'cycling': 0, 'running': 0, 'swimming': 0, 'total': 0}),
 ('turnerb3',
  {'cycling': 0, 'running': 1180.0, 'swimming': 500, 'total': 1680.0}),
 ('alim2',
  {'cycling': 0, 'running': 1470.0, 'swimming': 650.0, 'total': 2120.0}),
 ('mahroosm5',
  {'cycling': 4877.0, 'running': 1180.0, 'swimming': 590, 'total': 6647.0})]
```

Also if you want it reversed you can add `reverse=True` argument.

Comment: That does sort the dictionary, but i want to print the username as the output; the username with the most calories burnt. Thanks